# how to get items between the search parameters

Tags: c#, .net, windows, linq, linq-to-objects

Work on C#.I have a list named as **InputList** .From this list I have to search Some string.After search I want to select all item between the search parameter.Bellow picture discribe in detail.

**Text Input File:**
[image]

Collection :
[image]

After read the **textFile** I store data in dataset then,convert the dataset as **collection** .From this collection i want to get valuse between the search parameters.

I write the bellow syntax but **r3** result can not satisfy me.

```
var InputList = (from p in ds.Tables["InputFile"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray() select p.ItemArray).ToList();

            var r3 = (from c in InputList
                      where c.Any(e => e.ToString().Contains("Loading")) 
                      select c).ToList();
```

If have any query plz ask.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What result did you get and what did you expect?

Comment: syntax is given ,Hope you get what's the output of r3.I already describe what i want?

Comment: What do you mean by "between the search parameters" ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the results between queries, the [`SkipWhile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075.aspx) and [`TakeWhile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx) would work (both have variants that give the index to the predicate), but I don't think that is quite what you want given your image.

```
var loadingIndexes = InputList.Select((r, i) => new { Row=row, Index=i })
                              .Where(x => x.Row.Any(e =>
                                  e.ToString().Contains("Loading"))
                              .Select(x => x.Index);
var betweenLines = loadingIndexes
                       .Select(i => InputList
                           .Skip(i)
                           .TakeWhile(r => !r.Any(e =>
                                                  e.ToString().Contains("FULL")))
                           .ToList())
                       .ToList();
```

Here `betweenLines` is a `List` of `List`s of `DataRow`s, where each list is between a `DataRow` containing the string "Loading" (inclusive) and the next `DataRow" containing the string "FULL" (exclusive).